# get_object_or_404 is undefined

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to update my Profile model with some data that I get from a form, but I get this error

```
name 'get_object_or_404' is not defined
```

Here's my code for the view (It's pretty basic at this point)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from users import models
from users.models import Profile
from .forms import WeightForm
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    profile = get_object_or_404(pk=id)
    form = WeightForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
    if form.is_valid():
       form.save

return render(request, 'Landing/index.html',{'form':form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import it. Furthermore in a [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404), you first specify a model class or a queryset, so in this case `get_object_or_404(Profile, …)`:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def home(request):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=id)
    form = WeightForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
    if form.is_valid():
       form.save()
    return render(request, 'Landing/index.html',{'form':form})
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.